# How to visualize the SpaCy word embedding as scatter plot?

Tags: matplotlib, machine-learning, nlp, spacy, word-embedding

Each word in SpaCy is represented by a vector of length 300. How can I plot these words on a scatter plot to get a visual perspective on how close any 2 words are?

Answer (score 3):

There's a new package called `whatlies` that does exactly this: https://rasahq.github.io/whatlies/

See a short spacy example: https://spacy.io/universe/project/whatlies

Answer (score 2):

When working with small-to-medium-sized texts, ScatterText is a tool which can be used to discover words that have distinguishing features. It also enables users to create interactive scatter plots that contain non-overlapping term labels.

Intall via -https://pypi.org/project/scattertext/

```
import spacy
import scattertext as st
nlp = spacy.load('en')
corpus = st.CorpusFromPandas(convention_df,
                         category_col='party',
                         text_col='text',
                         nlp=nlp).build()
```